# Sorting array of DOM nodes from top-level to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, sorting

I have an array (a javascript array, not a jQuery object) of DOM nodes that acts as a queue for a function I have that processes them. This array could potentially contain elements that have parent/child, grandparent/child, etc. relationships. I always want higher-level elements to be processed first. My first inclination was to whip up a quicksort function in javascript, but I knew it would be faster if I could use javascript's native `Array.prototype.sort` method.

I tried it this way:

```
domElements.sort(function (a, b) {
  return $(a).find(b).length ? 1 :
         $(b).find(a).length ? -1 :
         0;
});
```

But it didn't seem to sort it perfectly. I would still sometimes have child elements before their parents. Why doesn't this work? Is there a way to do this with javascript's native sort?

**UPDATE**: After surveying the methods in the answers, I wanted to know how they performed. [Here](http://jsperf.com/sort-array-of-dom-nodes-parent-to-child) are the results. Feel free to tweak and see how the performance is for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save some time by using jQuery's `unique` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

```
jQuery.unique(domElements);
```

Comment: This ran the fastest according to my test results (see updated answer). Thanks!

Comment: @benekastah: A great example of the value of using someone else's tested and optimized code rather than roll-your-own! I'm pleased to have come second in most of the tests, but not surprised to be beaten by `unique`. :-)

Comment: If you guys are curious why this is so much faster, I think I found it [here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L961). It uses the native `domEl.compareDocumentPosition` method in browsers that support it. Although, `jQuery.unique` still wins in IE7-8, where this method isn't supported, even though jQuery is doing a much more comprehensive sort than the others. Hats off to jQuery/Sizzle on this one.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L983)'s where it's faster in IE.

Answer (score 1):

*(Since you asked me to post it. :-) )*

You've said you want the parent elements *before* the children in the array, but your code

```
domElements.sort(function (a, b) {
  return $(a).find(b).length ? 1 :
         $(b).find(a).length ? -1 :
         0;
});
```

...returns `1` if `a` is a parent of `b`, which will put `a` *later* in the array than `b`.

So I'm thinking:

```
domElements.sort(function (a, b) {
  return $(a).find(b).length ? -1 :
         $(b).find(a).length ? 1 :
         0;
});
```

But checking if an element is a descendant of another element is so straight-forward, I wonder if you really need the allocate-a-jQuery-object-and-then-call-find:

```
domElements.sort(function (a, b) {
  return isParentOf(a, b) ? -1 :
         isParentOf(b, a) ? 1 :
         0;
});

function isParentOf(parent, elm) {
    while (elm) {
        elm = elm.parentNode;
        if (elm === parent) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/ojenuy) But note [timmywil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9215967/157247) — even though it does a bit of unnecessary work (putting the siblings in order, when all you care about is parent/child), there's a pre-baked jQuery function for that!

Comment: I did not realize how easy it was to check if an element descends from another. Indeed, this resulted in a very healthy speed increase as compared to my version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I mixed around the negative sign on the one:

```
domElements.sort(function (a, b) {
  return $(a).find(b).length ? -1 :
         $(b).find(a).length ? 1 :
         0;
});
```

Seems to work.

Comment: Yup, was just posting that. Just as a side note, it may be more efficient to just do the search yourself (it's not much of a loop), rather than doing the full allocate-a-jquery-object-then-call-find-on-it thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Post that as an answer. I'd be happy to look at it. I'd rather accept someone else's answer instead of my own anyway :)

Comment: `@benekastah`: Well, since you *asked*...posted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting random elements in a document according to their source code order  will 
keep childnodes and siblings in their proper positions.

```
if(!Array.prototype.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf= function(what, i){
        if(typeof i!= 'number') i= 0;
        var L= this.length;
        while(i< L){
            if(this[i]=== what) return i;
            ++i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
function nodeSort(nodesArray, pa){
    pa= pa || document;
    var original= [], src= pa.getElementsByTagName('*'), L= src.length;
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        if(nodesArray.indexOf(src[i])!=-1) original.push(src[i]);
    }
    return nodesArray.sort(function(a, b){
        return original.indexOf(a)- original.indexOf(b);
    });
}
```